# Disable x or y snap in jQuery UI draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I have app where i need only snap element to top and bottom edges of parent element. I try to find how to do it in stack but i can't find it!

Answer (score 0):

```
el.draggable({
        start: function(){
            var snapped = $(this).data('draggable').snapElements;
            snapped.forEach(function(el){
                el.width = 1000000;
                el.left = -50000;
            });
        }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is doing the snapping manually instead of relying on the draggable's  functionality. E.g. you can disable the snapping and in your `drag` handle implement it by changing the object's position whenever it's close enough to whatever location you like.

Here's a solution for the similar request: [Getting jQuery draggable to snap to specific grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695744/getting-jquery-draggable-to-snap-to-specific-grid)

Comment: As for me manual snapping it's additional pile of code, but when you need something very custom it's may be worked better...