# Getting JQuery UI Draggable to snap to a specific grid (with a twist)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am currently trying to apply a "drag and drop" - functionality to a bunch of elements using jQuery and jQuery UI. It should be noted, that the elements should always snap to a specific grid when being dragged. I was very happy to see that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695744/getting-jquery-draggable-to-snap-to-specific-grid) [@Nate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/399077/nate) already explained the functionality very well. The problem I'm facing is, that the grid the draggable elements should snap to should be oriented to the droppable element AND the draggable elements are no children to the droppable element.

In detail, the draggable elements of varying sizes should always snap to a grid consisting of 40x40 cells oriented to a droppable (in my example 400x400, so a 10x10 grid), thats in another part of my html. The main problem i'm facing is, that i can't seem to get the orientation of my snapping grid to align with my droppable. Here's my current approach in javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".draggable").draggable({
        revert: true,
        revertDuration: 0,
        snap: true,
        snapTolerance: 40,
        containment: ".container",

        drag: function( event, ui ) {
            var snapTolerance = $(this).draggable('option', 'snapTolerance');

            //get positions of the own board and the currently dragged element relative to the document
            var ownBoardPositionRelToDoc = $("#droppable").offset();
            var uiPositionRelToDoc = ui.helper.offset();

            var topDiffToDoc = ui.helper.offset().top - ui.position.top;
            var leftDiffToDoc = ui.helper.offset().left - ui.position.left;

            console.log(ownBoardPosition);
            console.log(uiPosition);

            topRemainder = ownBoardPosition.top % 40;
            leftRemainder = ownBoardPosition.left % 40;

            if (topRemainder <= snapTolerance) {
                ui.position.top = ui.helper.offset().top - topRemainder;
            }

            if (leftRemainder <= snapTolerance) {
                ui.position.left = ui.helper.offset().left - leftRemainder;
            }
        }
    });

    $(".droppable").droppable({
        accept: ".draggable",
        tolerance: "fit",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this));
        }
    });

});
```

I've constructed [a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwd4semk/5/) to explain my idea further. Sadly it's not executable due to JQuery UI not being supported but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: true,
    revertDuration: 0,
    containment: ".container",
    grid: [40, 40]
  });

  $(".droppable").droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
    tolerance: "fit",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this));
    }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/rLx7jtob/

You can use `grid` to make it easier.

https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-grid

> Snaps the dragging helper to a grid, every x and y pixels. The array must be of the form `[ x, y ]`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly using the basic grid functionality of JQuery UI doesn't work, if the draggables are no children to the droppable (as i said, in a different div in another part of my html-website). I'm currently trying a different html solution to get the children into the droppable beforehand. Gonna report back with a possible solution soon.

Comment: @Tired8296 please provide a [mcve] that shows this. As you did not provide it in your exmaple, there was not a way to know or understand your meaning. When the element is dropped, you can at that time append it as a child and set it's position to be what you prefer. Your statement, '...elements should always snap to a specific grid when being dragged,' contradicts your comment. Maybe a drawing of what you are expecting might help.

Comment: After finishing the project i can tell you that i didn't really know what i wanted and/or expected. Your answer regarding the grid functionality was correct and i essentially needed to manually define a dropzone inside of my droppable, that matched the needs of my project. The Drag-and-Drop-Functionality of JQuery UI is simply not made for projects like mine and i needed to learn more about it to realize that. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @Tired8296 it does a good job for what it is and you are right, if you need more precise control, it does leave a lot to be desired.